# An experiment related to Faraday's laws

Tags: electromagnetism

[image]

This question is out of an Indian competition. I do not know calculus yet. I have some idea about how magnetic fields and electric fields work together but i don't know how to go about thinking about the question. I have some idea about what is going to happen in Q because of [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NqdOyxJZj0U) video.

The answer to the question as given in the answer key is (3). I can't intuitively understand how removing a part of the ring stops it from being affected from the magnetic field (a bit at least).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the start as the rings fall the magnetic flux through them increases and so an emf is induced in each of them.

According to Lenz if there is an induced current it would flow in such a direction as to oppose the motion producing it.
In the example given if there was an induced current it would be in a clockwise direction if one observed from the top.
Such an induced current would produce an upward force in opposition to the gravitational attraction of the Earth this would reduce the acceleration of a ring.

As plastic is an insulator there is no induced current in the plastic ring and so no opposition to the motion and ignoring air resistance the only force on the plastic ring is the gravitational attraction.

For the copper ring with a gap in it there is no complete electrical circuit and any induced currents will be very, very small thus the only force acting on the ring would be gravitational attraction.
So both these rings would fall at the same rate.

However for the complete copper ring there is a complete electrical circuit and so a significant induced current will flow which will produce an upward force.
Thus the net downward force on that ring will be less than that for the other two rings and so it will have a smaller downward acceleration and arrive last.

I have never seen a demonstration with a hollow magnet however there are many examples of a magnet falling through a copper pipe.
[Here is one of them which shows what a large effect in can be.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E97CYWlALEs)

Answer (score 1):

Removing a part of the rings prevents currents from going round in the ring. If there is no current, there is no magnetic field, and therefore there is no force to break the fall.

Thus the "broken" ring and the plastic ring fall with the same velocity.